# mlogit in Stata and R

Tags: r, stata, multiple-choice, mlogit

I have one question concerning the mlogit command in Stata and/or R. In the model I’m working on the individuals don’t face the same choice set each other; for example I have 10 alternatives but for some customers the choice set is reduced to 8. Is it possible to take this into account when I use mlogit? 
Thank you very much for your attention

Answer (score 0):

Use [MNP](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MNP/). For implementation see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28776/multinomial-probit-for-varying-choice-set):

> If the choice set varies from one observation to another, use the
>   syntax, cbind(y1, y2, y3) ~ x1 + x2, in the case of a three choice
>   problem, and indicate unavailable alternatives by NA. If only the most
>   preferred choice is observed, y1, y2, and y3 are indicator variables
>   that take on the value one for individuals who prefer that choice and
>   zero otherwise. The last column of the response matrix, y3 in this
>   particular example syntax, is used as the base category.